# Solution for two variable transcendental equation

Tags: transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

How to find the solution for a two variable transcendental equation?
The following is the equation:

$$a^5+ab^4+2a^3b^2\cos(100a)\cosh(100b)+(a^4b-a^2b^3)\sin(100a)\sinh(100b)=0$$

I know that there are infinite solutions for this equation. What is the best and efficient way to find solution and graph this equation?

Comment: This is almost impossible to read! People will be much more likely to help you if you use MathJax/LaTeX formatting, FYI.

Comment: If you enclose your equations with dollar signs it will format it using LaTeX.

Comment: I am new to stack exchange. Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this equation?